# How to get badge count for floating button in android?

Tags: android

I have refered this below link to get floating button.But I want to show the badge count on the floating button.(The floating button is adjusted a way that we can move it all over the screen). How can i set the badge count on it?
Here without onclick I want to display floating icon with text(badge).  How I can do it?

https://droidqd.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/how-to-make-a-floating-face-bubble-on-home-screen-in-android/

```
 Edit :

This is the logcat output:

    12-01 18:32:09.943: D/AndroidRuntime(1252): Shutting down VM
12-01 18:32:09.943: D/AndroidRuntime(1252): --------- beginning of crash
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252): Process: com.example.floatingbubble, PID: 1252
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.ImageView{30ba5217 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-72,72} not attached to window manager
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:396)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:322)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:111)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at com.example.floatingbubble.FloatingFaceBubbleService$1.onTouch(FloatingFaceBubbleService.java:67)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8465)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2049)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5807)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5781)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5752)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5897)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
12-01 18:32:10.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1252):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
12-01 18:32:10.128: I/art(1252): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 888(178KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 56% free, 395KB/907KB, paused 1.900ms total 189.650ms
12-01 18:32:24.830: I/Process(1252): Sending signal. PID: 1252 SIG: 9
12-01 18:32:28.157: D/OpenGLRenderer(1327): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
```

Comment: you need to design a layout for your `FloatingBubbleService` her it is simply adding a view i.e `ImageView` to it what you can do is design a layout of how you want the service to look.. and instead of adding the `ImageView` you can add a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` to it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to design a layout for your `FloatingBubbleService` her it is simply adding a view i.e `ImageView` to it what you can do is design a layout of how you want the service to look.. and instead of adding the `ImageView` you can add a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` to it..

for e.g.

```
private TextView tv;
private RelativeLayout rl;
//code..
//inside your onCreate()
rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setText(badgeCount+"");//Badge Count
rl.addView(floatingFaceBubble);
rl.addView(tv);
//and instead of windowManager.addView(floatingFaceBubble, myParams);
windowManager.addView(rl, myParams);
```

## Note: The Code above won't work as is.. but is just here to give you some idea on how to go about solving your problem.

And whenever you need to update the text oon `Textview` just do it by doing `tv.setText()` call its is upto you how you call it..

```
//instead of floatingFaceBubble.setOnTouchListener use
rl.setOnTouchListener
//and instead of this windowManager.removeView(floatingFaceBubble); use
windowManager.removeView(rl);
```

Comment: Thank you Minato ..I will try @Minato

Comment: I tried ..I am getting this error...java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.ImageView{826a567 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-72,72} not attached to window manager  @Minato

Comment: @Shreya can you give me a complete stack trace?

Comment: I have added my logcat output in my quetion above..Please go through.. @Minato

Comment: @Shreya I updated my answer.. But please have a look at the bottom of the answer